# Extracting a Git repository out of CVS

Tags: cvs2git

I am using **cvs2git** which is a part of **cvs2svn** to convert my CVS repository to a Git repository.

I ran the command the following command,

```
python cvs2git --dumpfile=C:\git\project\git-dump.bin --blob=C:\git\project\git-blob.bin --username=cvs2git C:\cvsroot\project
```

the software did some processing and generated a **dump** and a **blob** file. What would I do with these files to extract a Git repository on which I can run the `git clone <url>` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run the following command.

```
cat git-dump.bin git-blob.bin | git fast-import
```

Comment: actually it's cat blob dump | git fast-import