# Transferring history of CVS to GIT

Tags: git, repository, cvs

We have the code base using CVS for long time. And now we are considering to move to git. The sources can be moved to GIT, no problem. But I want to know, how the history or the changes in CVS can be moved to the git.

For example, assume in  CVS, 1st day there is a commit by user 1. 2nd day another commit by user2. Also, 3rd day by user3. History of the changes can be seen in CVS as different days as well as different users. If the code base is moved to git from CVS, how those changes can be tranfer to GIT ? Is there any implementation to do when transferring from CVS to GIT?

Comment: There's an entire [cvs2git tag category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cvs2git) on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As torek commented, the tool to migrate not just the sources but the full history is **[cvs2git](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~jacob/cvs2svn/cvs2git.html)**.

You can see it in action in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23201786/6309) for instance:

> `python cvs2git --dumpfile=C:\git\project\git-dump.bin --blob=C:\git\project\git-blob.bin --username=cvs2git C:\cvsroot\project`

```
cat git-dump.bin git-blob.bin | git fast-import
```